# Instantiate does not work on Android

Tags: c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine

I'm instantiating prefabs in a grid. This works well on PC, but does not do anything on my Android device. Any suggestions?

```
public GameObject box;
public int amountOfBoxes = 13;
public int[,] grid = new int[13,4];

private int x;
private int y;
private int i;

void Start () {
    i = 0;
    while (i<amountOfBoxes){
        x = Random.Range(3, 9);
        y = Random.Range(0, 4);
        while(grid[x, y] == 1){
            x = Random.Range(3, 9);
            y = Random.Range(0, 4);
        }
        grid[x, y] = 1;
        Instantiate(box, new Vector2(x * 2.0F, y * 2.0F), Quaternion.identity);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried out the code and it worked on my device. Probably because of your orientation. Try setting it to landscape in Player Settings.

Comment: tried this. but still not working :/

Comment: well then try instantiating a box at 0, 0, 0. if it appears on your device then maybe your camera size isn't big enough. but if it doesn't then probably something is wrong with your device, haha...